# SQLite Question: How can i get in a Specific Row all datas which are not null?

Tags: sqlite

Ok, It will be much clearer once if done a Example:

```
RowId Name ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7 ID8 ID9 ID10
1     Alex  11  22  0   0   0   0   14  44  0    0
2     John   0  23  0   0   44  0   33  88  0   77
```

Ok, i want to get following result:

```
Alex   11  22  14  44
```

So the first part of the Query is clear,

```
Select * 
from Table
where Name = Alex AND *Now im not sure if i need to use IS NOT NULL or => 1*
```

Comment: null or 0? Not that it matters much; you have to know which columns you want in advance.

Comment: Doesnt matter for me if value is 0 or NULL. I want the query to give me only results with value.

Comment: Just to be clear, 0 or NULL only depends on what i enter as Default, so in this Example the 0 represent the default. The reason i am asking is, the Table will have lots of collumns, and i dont want to have all of them, which dont have a value in it, or only the default value.

Comment: @Ninbushi  Well, it matters to the query language and others from whom you are asking for help.  It is important to be precise in describing what you want.  In other words, you want *all non-null integer values greater than 0*.  "Results with value" is not very meaningful in most programming contexts since "value" is a rather abstract concept.  NULL and 0 have distinct meanings.

Comment: Yes, i know. for me it depends on what will work, if the Expression will be "NOT NULL" then these default values will be NULL. What i actually thought of, if i do the ``` Select* from Table where Name = Alex AND ´ID*` >= 0 ``` would that work if the 0 in my example stand for a INTEGER 0 ?

Comment: You **cannot exclude columns based on WHERE condition**... you can only exclude or include rows.   The problem is that the data is not normalized.  Your table should probably be like `rowID  Name  IDValue`, so there would be multiple rows for Alex and multiple rows for John.  A more complete normalization would include another related `Person` table with a name and id value which is then used as a foreign key in the IDValues table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will produce the required result :-

```
SELECT  
    Name ||' '||
    CASE WHEN coalesce(id1,0) <> 0 THEN id1||' ' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN coalesce(id2,0) <> 0 THEN id2||' ' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN coalesce(id3,0) <> 0 THEN id3||' ' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN coalesce(id4,0) <> 0 THEN id4||' ' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN coalesce(id5,0) <> 0 THEN id5||' ' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN coalesce(id6,0) <> 0 THEN id6||' ' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN coalesce(id7,0) <> 0 THEN id7||' ' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN coalesce(id8,0) <> 0 THEN id8||' ' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN coalesce(id9,0) <> 0 THEN id9||' ' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN coalesce(id10,0) <> 0 THEN id10||' ' ELSE '' END
    AS myidlist
    
FROM mytable
WHERE Name = 'Alex'
;
```

- the [coalesce](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) function, as used,turns null into 0 simplyfying the condition check. An alternative would be to use `CASE WHEN id1 <> 0 AND id1 IS NOT NULL THEN id1||' ' ELSE '' END`

[image]

**However**, the result will possibly be of little use or complicated to manipulate as a result (e.g. where do the numeric values come from such as what does 22 mean other than it's one of the values stored in one of the ID? columns).

## Alternative approach

- This approach assumes that you have a variable number of values per name (this may not necessarily be what you want).

Consider the following that, rather than using numerous columns to store the values **RELATED** to a name (related highlighted as SQLite is a relational database), it stores those values in a related table using a one-to-many relationship (there are many values each is realted to 1 name).

This bit creates the alternative structure/schema i.e. 2 tables one for the parent data another for the child data (the parent can have 0- many children each being a value)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable2 (Name TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable2_ids (
    Name_reference TEXT 
        REFERENCES mytable2(Name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE -- optional Foreign Key
        ,
    id INTEGER
);
```

This inserts the data equivalent to you original data.

```
INSERT INTO mytable2 VALUES('Alex'),('John');
INSERT INTO mytable2_ids VALUES 
    ('Alex',11),('Alex',22),('Alex',14),('Alex',44)
    ,   ('John',23),('John',44),('John',33),('John',88),('John',77)
;
```

This is the query that produces the same result :-

```
SELECT Name||group_concat(id,' ') AS myidlist FROM mytable2 JOIN mytable2_ids ON Name = Name_reference WHERE name = 'Alex';
```

- **group_concat** is an aggregate function that concatenates all the values of a group of data. In this case the group is all of the data as there is no GROUP BY clause. So it takes ALL of the values in the id columnof the JOINED (related) mytable2_ids and concatenates them.

The result being :-

[image]

Comment: Hello MikeT. Thanks for your Answer. The Integer Values will be used in C# to have a Item Database, each integer represents a Item the character will own. So, is there a Way, to have the select statement more "generic"? I actually found something about the GLOB (GLOB '*EN'). But i do not know how to use. The Format the Result is given in this case is not important for me, as i read only the result values, not the column Identifiers.  So the Result could also be in SQLite terms: ' Name  ID1 ID2 ..' and then under it 'Alex 11  22 ....'     Sorry, i dont know how to format in Comment correctly.

Comment: @Ninbushi unless you change the structure/schema then no you cannot be more generic. In short you appear to be wanting to store a list of values as columns when you possibly want to store related data e.g. a variable number of values per user.

Comment: Sorry, i do not really understand this Part of your comment:  "In short you appear to be wanting to store a list of values as columns when you possibly want to store related data e.g. a variable number of values per user."  I am not sure how i could store lots of Integer IDs for a specific "User" / "Char" in another way than in Columns? Especially if i need to add more collumns during runtime?  What is about the GLOB Operator? Would that help, to select the IDs where the value is greater than 0? I actually dont get that to work in any way.

Comment: @Ninbushi the answer has been updated to show an example using you data **BUT** stored as **related** data.

Comment: Thanks again. It looks like that i struggle with the understanding what can be done with the Select Statement. I do have Problems with what i am able tu use under select and what syntax it has to be. So you used the Case Operater under the Select Statement, to only select the collumns that do have a value higher than 0 , right? hmmm, i think i run into a wall :-) Looks like my directin of thinking was wrong. I thought it would be possible to use all Operators in the select clause on the columnsNames, but it looks like thats not possible :-(

Comment: @Ninbushi *So you used the Case Operater ....higher than 0 , right?* Not really.  What immediately follows SELECT is the list of result-columns. Often this is a list of columns, but derived values can be generated from expressions. The expression used was roughly saying concatentate (`||`) the **Name** column with either an empty string if the value of the id1 column is 0 or null otherwise the value stored in the **id1** column and then concatentate likewise for id2....id10. The result column then being named (`AS`) **myids**. see [SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Comment: I Edited my Question, could you have a look at this Aproach? Thank you very much

Comment: @Ninbushi, No. (that is not really any different other than the code would be shorter until 10 or more users would be added when it then gets to be longer). I've rolled back your edit. You need to research and consider the answer I've given, perhaps especially the **Alternative Approach**. You should also tick the asnwer as it does answer the question.